# Audio streaming in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to stream audio from an android phone to my pc but I keep getting an Exception.

When pressing the send button it used to be a code that records audio and stream it to the same phone but I altered it to send the recorded data over a socket.

I think it's a memory Exception but what should I do?

```
byte[] buffer = null;
            byte[] byteBuf = null;
             byte[][]   buffers;
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnStart: {
                Toast.makeText(AudioRecordingActivity.this, "Start Recording",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                enableButtons(true);
                //here is where I start my code
                 AudioRecord recorder = null;
                 boolean stopped =false;
                   // AudioTrack track = null;
                    buffers  = new byte[65535 ][160000 ];
                    int ix = 0;





                    /*
                     * Initialize buffer to hold continuously recorded audio data, start recording, and start
                     * playback.
                     */
                    try
                    {
                          try {
                                socket = new Socket("172.16.231.125",4444);
                                socketOutputStream =socket.getOutputStream();
                                Toast.makeText(AudioRecordingActivity.this, "Socket was made",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                Toast.makeText(AudioRecordingActivity.this, "Problem",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        int N = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                        recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, N*10);
                       // track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000, 
                              //  AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, N*10, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                        recorder.startRecording();
                        //track.play();
                        /*
                         * Loops until something outside of this thread stops it.
                         * Reads the data from the recorder and writes it to the audio track for playback.
                         */
                        while(true)
                        {
                             buffer = buffers[ix++ % buffers.length];
                            N = recorder.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
                            //ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(2*N);
                          // byteBuf = new byte[2*N];
                           /* int i = 0;
                            while (N >= i) {
                                byte b = (byte)(buffer[i]/256); 
                                byteBuf[i]=b;

                                i++;
                            }*/


                            //byte [] bb = byteBuf.array();

                            try {
                                 socketOutputStream.write( buffer );
                                    socketOutputStream.flush();
                                Toast.makeText(AudioRecordingActivity.this, "Data was sent",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(AudioRecordingActivity.this, "can't send",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                Toast.makeText(AudioRecordingActivity.this, "can't send",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            //track.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);






                        }
                    }
                    catch(Throwable x)
                    { 

                        Toast.makeText(AudioRecordingActivity.this,"Error reading voice audio",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Comment: _"I keep getting an Exception"_ Then you should include information about the exception in your question (the _exact_ logcat output).

Comment: Probably yet another case of the network on main thread exception.  And then many other challenges to learn about and solve.

Comment: Do you have the original source code?